# TrayIcon Custom Notification balloon java

Tags: java, trayicon

I did search but couldn't find anything.

Okay, so I wanted to have a custom "balloon" look for TrayIcon.displayMessage(args). I was wondering if this is possible using pre-defined functions/methods? Or would I just create a new undecorated frame for a set amount of time then dispose of it? This obviously is not the best way of doing it. If anyone knows of anything about the TrayIcon notification balloon, could you post?

Comment: Java does not seem to have a way to do it natively. You could look into writing it in a .net language, and calling the non-java code using Java Native Interface.